# I want to send out a mail when an activity is retrying after an initial failure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Azure Data factory pipeline in which have a activity that runs a sql script. I have retry setup on Activity for it to run again after its fails on first run. I want to send an email when it fails on its first run and is retrying.

I have tried to set up a failure output from activity to send a mail. But it will retry without sending the mail (through web activity).

I want to send email once it fails in its first run and is retrying on second run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `Alert` in Azure Data Factory (ADF) `Monitor` section under `Alerts and Metrics` option.

1. Go to `Monitor` section on ADF Studio and click on `Alerts and Metrics` then `New alert rule` as shown below.

[image]

2. Give a **alert rule name** to new alert rule. Provide a **description** about the rule. Give a **Severity** for this alert and then click on `+ Add criteria` for this alert.

[image]

3. From the given list, choose the `Failed activity runs metrics` criteria and click on **Continue**. This will create a criteria for the failed activity based on your `Configuration alert logic` in next step. Under configuration you can mention the **count** for how each time the activity fails you will get the alert.

[image]

4. Now click on `+ Configure Notification` option in step 2 image.
5. Give an `action name`. Under `Select which notification you'd like to receive` check mark **Email** and give the email address on which you want to give alert. Click on `Add notification`.

Now you will get notification every time the activity fail.

[image]

**Note:** The retry you should mention in the activity level to run it required number of times after failure. You will get the failure alert for each time the activity re-run and fail.

To know more check official document [Data Factory metrics and alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-metrics-alerts#data-factory-alerts).