# how to add failure control of each stage in ADF

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

if any of my stage fails, I need to pick it up from the same failed  stage in my next run instead of starting from the first stage, how to achieve this is ADF? and how to send email whenever an stage fails so that all the users are notified?

Answer (score 1):

> if any of my stage fails, I need to pick it up from the same failed stage in my next run instead of starting from the first stage, how to achieve this is ADF?

**Failde activity**

[image]

To Rerun this pipeline from copy activity, **click on Rerun from this activity symbol**

[image]

Click on **`Ok`**

[image]

***Output***

It skipped first wait activity which is already runned successfully and started from copy activity which is failed.

[image]

> how to send email whenever a stage fails so that all the users are notified?

For failure alert for each activity an alert can be created in the Azure Data Factory (ADF) Monitor section under the Alerts and Actions option.

For more understanding you can refer this ***[SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72254623)*** by @UtkarshPal-MT

**Or else**,

You can create a logic app and then configure it with Azure Data factory through that you cand send mail when activity fails you

For more information you can refer this [Article](https://kohera.be/azure-cloud/custom-email-notification-in-azure-data-factory/#:%7E:text=Add%20an%20activity%20on%20failure,by%20dragging%20the%20red%20arrow.&text=Now%20we%20need%20to%20adjust%20the%20parameters.&text=Now%20our%20solution%20is%20ready,notification%20is%20up%20and%20running.) by **@JEROEN SMANS**